# Удалить множество элементов

Tags: java

Вообще у меня есть массив индексов из массива(`ArrayList`) и необходимо удалить элементы по данным индексам. Вся проблема в том, что когда я удаляю элемент по индексу, то индексы имеют свойство после удаления меняться. Можно как-то на java пометить элементы для удаления, а потом махом удалить, или что-нибудь подобное или какое-нибудь решение?

Comment: Может вы не те коллекции для своих задач используете? Для вас важен порядок? Если нет, то используйте HashSet и удаляйте на здоровье.

Answer (score 4):

Если отсортировать индексы по убыванию, то можно безболезненно удалять элементы в соответствии с порядком индексов. Но каждое удаление будет приводить к перемещению элементов внутри массива, на котором основан список, что является не эффективным решением.

Более эффективный вариант, как мне кажется, это создание нового экземпляра `ArrayList` с заранее заданным размером, который равен длинне оригинального списка заминусом длинны массива индексов. После этого можно пройтись по оригинальному списку один раз и скопировать только те элементы, которые не помечены на удаление.

Comment: Понимаете даже один полный проход массива стоит дорого. Там порядка 100000+ элементов.

Comment: @Wolkodav Удаление элемента из массива (ArrayList) не является дешевой операцией. Как только мы удаляем необходимый элемент, все элементы правее него сдвигаются на позицию левее, в то время как вставка элемента в список в среднем производится за постоянное время. Поэтому, логичнее отсортировать индексы в порядке возрастания, и удаление начать с наибольшего индекса. Чем больше в Вашем списке на удаление элементов, тем более эффективным станет вариант с копированием в новый список. только не надо зыбывать указывать "емкость" типа `new ArrayList(sourceArray.size() - toDelete.size())`

Answer (score 1):

Если надо удалять много элементов, то стоит взять структуру, которая для этого заточена, а именно `LinkedList`.

Создайте связанный список на основе вашего массива (как пример):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("a");
        add("b");
        add("c");
    }};
LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>(list);
```

удалите в нём все, что нужно за один проход и верните новый список:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(linkedList.size());
Collections.copy(newList,linkedList);
```

UPD:
Примерно вот так будет выглядеть удаление:

```
int count = -1;
Iterator<String> it = linkedList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()){
     count++;
     if (indexes.contains(count))
         it.remove();
}
```

Возможно, также было бы полезно отсортировать индексы:

```
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        ...
}};
Collections.sort(indexes);
```

Comment: Хм, а вот это уже заманчиво, а пример удаления можно?

Comment: Странно. Вариант с полным копированием ArrayList в LinkedList а затем обработка LinkedList более заманчив, чем копирование нужных данных без обработок?

Comment: Я нигде не утверждал, что это единственное и правильное решение. В данном случае основная идея - использование `LinkedList` вместо `ArrayList` при необходимости частого удаления элементов.